# Staying in Leuven for Werchter 2019, how can I get from the train to my hotel?

Tags: safety, belgium, night-transport

I booked a hotel near the city center of Leuven, and there are shuttles to Leuven train station after the shows end in Werchter.
It's about a 1.5 km walk to my hotel, and I'm concerned about safety. If I get back late in the evening (2-3am), can I walk or use busses without worrying? 
Alternatively, will there be taxis waiting at this hour in the train station? Or Uber?

Thanks.

Comment: Leuven is considered a safe city. The only thing you'll see are drunken students.
Leuven is big enough to have taxi's 24/7, especially during Werchter they expect more people.
As far as I know Uber isn't that known/used in Leuven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 1,5 km walk should be quite safe. But if this does not feel comfortable for you, there should be taxi's available in the railway station : http://www.belgianrail.be/en/stations-and-train/search-a-station/4/leuven.aspx and there are some buses at night also, depending on the location of your hotel : https://www.delijn.be/en/avond-nachtvervoer/nachtvervoer-leuven.html?vertaling=true

Comment: Can I expect the taxis to be available 24/7 there?